# Convert protobuf to flnk schema

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

I am using py-flink to read protobuf and write it to table, protobuf like:

```
message test {
  int id = 1;
  string val = 2;
}
```

Actually, the protobuf desc is too long, so I don't wan't write the schema like

```
Schema()\.
    .field('id', DataTypes.BIGINT())\
    .field('val', DataTypes.STRING())
```

How can I do?

I found I can use pyflink.table.protobuf.ProtobufSchemaConverter to convert the protobuf desc to flink schema like:

```
ProtobufSchemaConverter().fromDescriptor(desc)
```

in py-flink 1.10, but I can't find this function in py-flink 1.16.